# Need Help Finding the intersection of two equations in Java

Tags: java

I saw someone else posted this problem but didn't word it properly so he didn't end up receiving any help, so I figured I would try and be more direct.

Here is the problem proposed to us :

// Write and submit your code in a file called Intersect.java. Use the IO module to read inputs. Use System.out.println() to print your answer.

Write a program that calculates the intersection between 2 equations:

a degree-2 (quadratic) polynomial i.e.

y = dx^2 + fx + g

where d, f, and g are constants

and a degree-1 (linear) equation i.e.

y = mx + b

where m is the slope and b is a constant

The above is just text, not code that could appear in a Java program.

Ask the user for the constant values in each equation. Output the intersection(s) as ordered pair(s) (x,y), or "none" if none exists. Below is an example run.

java Intersect

Enter the constant d:
5
Enter the constant f:
-3
Enter the constant g:
2
Enter the constant m:
1
Enter the constant b:
3

The intersection(s) is/are:
(1,4)
(-0.20,2.8)
//

The main problem is essentially asking us to write a code that asks the user to imput the individual constants and the slope of the two equations, one being a quadratic polynomial and the other being a linear equation in point-slope.

I understand that we have to use the quadratic equation in the code, however I have no idea how to actually code this in.

Once we have had the user imput the constants, in this case 5 (d,f,g,m,b; with m being slope)  we need to have the code run the calculations to imput those constants into the above example ( y = dx^2 + fx + g  |  y = mx + b)  and return either "none" if there is no intersection, or if it does intersect, the ordered pair at which it does intersect (x,y).

I know already that if 0 is entered as the constants it returns (NaN,NaN) which I also know needs to be re-written to None.

so far I only have the following:

public class Intersect {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    System.out.println("Enter the constant d:");
    int d = IO.readInt();

    System.out.println("Enter the constant f:");
    int f = IO.readInt();

    System.out.println("Enter the constant g:");
    int g = IO.readInt();

    System.out.println("Enter the constant m:");
    int m = IO.readInt();

    System.out.println("Enter the constant b:");
    int b = IO.readInt();
```

If anyone can shed some light on this that would be fantastic, thanks!

EDIT1 :

So far i've changed the code to the following, however, I still don't know how to get it to return to me an answer:

public class Intersect {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    System.out.println("Enter the constant d:");
    int d = IO.readInt();

    System.out.println("Enter the constant f:");
    int f = IO.readInt();

    System.out.println("Enter the constant g:");
    int g = IO.readInt();

    System.out.println("Enter the constant m:");
    int m = IO.readInt();

    System.out.println("Enter the constant b:");
    int b = IO.readInt();


    //y = dx^2 + fx + g
    //y = mx + b

    //mx + b = dx^2 + fx + g

    //x^2 * (d)  +   x * ( f - m )  +  ( g - b )

    int A = d;
    int B =  f - m;
    int C =  g - b;


    double x1 = - B + Math.sqrt(  B^2  -  4 * A * C ) / (2 * A);
    double x2 = - B - Math.sqrt(  B^2  -  4 * A * C ) / (2 * A);


    double y1 = m * x1 + b;
    double y2 = m * x1 + b;
```

}

Also, eclipse is telling me that x2,y1, and y2 aren't used at all.
I know I need to use System.out.println()  however I don't understand what I can put there to make the answer an ordered pair.  Also, I tried setting an If statement to have the answer return None instead of NaN however it instead returns, NaN None.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of special cases you have to take into account.
I hope I've got them all right.

So after the initialization of the values you can put this:

```
// calculating some useful values.
        double t = -(f - m) / (2.0 * d);
        double u = t * t - (g - b) / (double) d;

        // the first polynomial is linear, so both terms are.
        if (d == 0) {
            // both linear functions have the same slope.
            if (f == m) {
                // both functions are shifted the same amount along the y-Axis.
                if (g == b)
                    // the functions lie on top of each other.
                    System.out.println("There is an infinite amount intersections");
                // the functions are shifted different amounts along the y-Axis.
                else
                    // the lines are parallel.
                    System.out.println("There are no intersections");
            }
            // both linear functions have different slopes.
            else {
                // solve linear equation.
                double x = (b - g) / (double) (f - m);
                double y = m * x + b;
                System.out.println("The intersection is: (" + x + "," + y + ")");
            }
        }
        // the functions do not cross each other.
        else if (u < 0)
            System.out.println("There are no intersections");
        // the linear function is a tangent to the quadratic function.
        else if (u == 0) {
            // solve equation.
            double x = t;
            double y = m * x + b;
            System.out.println("The intersection is: (" + x + "," + y + ")");
        }
        // the linear function intersects the quadratic function at two points.
        else {
            // solve quadratic equation.
            double x1 = t + Math.sqrt(u);
            double x2 = t - Math.sqrt(u);
            double y1 = m * x1 + b;
            double y2 = m * x2 + b;
            System.out.println("The intersections are: (" + x1 + "," + y1 + ") (" + x2 + "," + y2 + ")");
        }
```

Comment: YOU! Sir or Madam, are a brilliant help.  So far it seems to work flawlessly! THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

i guess....

```
//y = dx^2 + fx + g
//y = mx + b

//mx + b = dx^2 + fx + g

//x^2 * (d)  +   x * ( f - m )  +  ( g - b )

A = d
B =  f - m 
C =  g - b 


x1 = - B + sqr(  B^2  -  4 * A * C ) / (2 * A)
x2 = - B - sqr(  B^2  -  4 * A * C ) / (2 * A)


y1 = m * x1 + b
y2 = m * x1 + b
```

Comment: Based on that the code only allows me to enter in the constants above, the math seems to be correct but the code doesnt actually do any of it.  So after it asks me for each individual variable it just stops.  I also had to delcare A,B,C,x1,x2,y1,y2 as integers, or should I declare them as doubles?

Comment: So, so far this is what I've done, and I know this may seem sloppy but theres no hiccups so far, however it doesnt solve the problem of returning an answer.
 I've added your imput to my original post as an edit.